# System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, react-hooks

`System.InvalidOperationException:` The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.

I am getting this error in console only on live environment it works efficiently on my local , it gives 500 Error.

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500
Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

This is middleware code

```
  app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                {
                    if (ctx.Context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/static"))
                    {
                        // Cache all static resources for 1 year (versioned filenames)
                        var headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                        headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                        {
                            Public = true,
                            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365)
                        };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Do not cache explicit `/index.html` or any other files.  See also: `DefaultPageStaticFileOptions` below for implicit "/index.html"
                        var headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                        headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                        {
                            Public = true,
                            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(0)
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is my react code when I click on See History this issues arise , See History basically opens a Pop Up and makes a call with API to bring data:

```
              <div>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleOpen} style={seeHistoryButtonStyles}>See History</Button>
                <Modal dialogClassName="modal-lg" style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} show={open} onHide={handleClose} >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Terms and Conditions History</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <HistoryItems fmoId={fmoId} resourceId={resourceId} />
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
            </div>

//And this is the file that opens up after clicking

import React, { useState, useEffect,useRef } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { getFmoTermsAndConditionsById } from "./../../../redux/actions/FmoValues";
import JoditEditor from 'jodit-react';
import  './styles.css';

const DetailedTermsAndConditions = () => {
const config = {
    toolbar: false,
    readonly: true,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    useSplitMode: false,
    showXPathInStatusbar: false,
    showCharsCounter: false,
    showWordsCounter: false,
    showPlaceholder: false,
    showTooltip: false,
    disablePlugins: 'paste',
};

const editor = useRef(null);
const [termsAndConditions, setTermsAndConditions] = useState("");
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const location = useLocation();
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
const termsId = searchParams.get("termsId");

useEffect(() => { 
    dispatch(getFmoTermsAndConditionsById(termsId));
}, [dispatch, termsId]);

const fmoValues = useSelector((state) => state.FmoValues);

useEffect(() => {
    if (fmoValues && fmoValues.termsAndConditions && fmoValues.termsAndConditions['termsAndConditions'])
    {
        setTermsAndConditions(fmoValues.termsAndConditions['termsAndConditions']);
    }
}, [fmoValues,termsId]);

return (

    <div className="termsAndConditionDiv" >
        <div className="headdingAndSubHeadingDiv">
            <h2>Portal</h2>
           <span className="termsAndConditionsTitle">Terms and Conditions</span>
        </div>
        <JoditEditor
            ref={editor}
            value={termsAndConditions}
            config={config}
        />
    </div>
    );
}
export default DetailedTermsAndConditions;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Http Post for Getting the Details from API , I changed it to Http Get and it resolved the issue.